# How do I run a for loop over all columns of a data frame and return the result as a separate data frame or matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to obtain the number of cases for each variable in a df. There are 275 cases in the df but most columns have some missing data. I am trying to run a for loop to obtain the information as follows:

```
idef_id<-readxl::read_xlsx("IDEF.xlsx")

casenums <- for (i in names(idef_id)) {
  nas<- sum(is.na(i))
  275-nas
}
```

however the output for `casenums` is

```
> summary(casenums)
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: (1) `i in names(idef_id)` and `sum(is.na(i))` is counting the number of `NA` in the *names* of your frame, not in the columns itself; perhaps `sum(is.na(idef_id[[i]]))`? (2) Better: `lapply(idef_id, function(z) 275 - sum(is.na(z)))`, though I caution against hard-coding `275`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate fix for your `for` loop is that your `i` is a column *name*, not the data within. On your first pass through the `for` loop, your `i` is class `character`, always length 1, so `sum(is.na(i))` is going to be 0. Due to how frames are structured, there is very little likelihood that a *name* is `NA` (though it is possible ... with manual subterfuge).

I suggest a literal fix for your code could be:

```r
casenums <- for (i in names(idef_id)) {
  nas<- sum(is.na(idef_id[[i]]))
  275-nas
}
```

But this has the added problem that `for` loops don't return anything (as Gregor's answer also discusses). For the sake of walking through things, I'll keep that (for the first bullet), and then fix it (in the second):

Two things:

- hard-coding `275` (assuming that's the number of rows in the frame) will be problematic if/when your data ever changes. Even if you're "confident" it never will ... I still recommend not hard-coding it. If it's based on the number of rows, then perhaps

  ```r
  OUT_OF <- 275 # should this be nrow(idef_id)?
  casenums <- for (i in names(idef_id)) {
    nas<- sum(is.na(idef_id[[i]]))
    OUT_OF - nas
  }
  ```

  at least in a *declarative* sense, where the variable name (please choose something better) is clear as to how you determined `275` and how (if necessary) it should be fixed in the future.

  (Or better, use Gregor's logic of `sum(!is.na(...))` if you just need to count not-`NA`.)
- doing something for each column of a frame is easily done using `sapply` or `lapply`, perhaps

  ```r
  OUT_OF <- 275 # should this be nrow(idef_id)?
  OUT_OF - sapply(idef_id, function(one_column) sum(is.na(one_column)))
  ## or
  sapply(idef_id, function(one_column) OUT_OF - sum(is.na(one_column)))
  ```

Comment: Many thanks r2evans, I think you're right, hard-coding 275 is not the best. nrow(idef_id) would work much better. Thanks for walking through it for me!

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop isn't a function - it doesn't return anything, so `x <- for(...` doesn't ever make sense. You can do that with, e.g., `sapply`, like this

```
casenums <- sapply(idef_id, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
```

Or you can do it in a for loop, but you need to assign to a particular value inside the loop:

```
casenums = rep(NA, ncol(idef_id))
names(casenums) = names(idef_id)
for(i in names(idef_id)) {
  casenums[i] = sum(!is.na(idef_id[[i]]))`
}
```

You also had a problem that `i` is taking on column names, so `sum(is.na(i))` is asking if the value of the column name is missing. You need to use `idef_id[[i]]` to access the actual column, not just the column name, as I show above.

You seem to want the answer to be the number of non-NA values, so I switched to `sum(!is.na(...))` to count that directly, rather than hard-coding the number of rows of the data frame and doing subtraction.

Comment: Many thanks Gregor, this is really helpful. the Not sure why I didn't go with !is.na in the first place! I'll give it a go.